# Listview update in ProgressChanged event slows down the application too much

Tags: c#, listview, events

I have a `ProgressChanged` event for download and in this event I update a `Listview` writing async threads statuses. But this operation slows down the program, even causes **Not Responding**. My code and an ss are below. How can I fix this problem.

```
private void downloader_ProgressChanged(object sender, EventArguments.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        progressBar1.Value = (int)(downloader.Progress * 100);
        if (downloader.Info.ContentSize > 0)
            lblContentSize.Text = downloader.Info.ContentSize.ToHumanReadableSize();
        lblSpeed.Text = downloader.Speed.ToHumanReadableSize() + "/s";
        lblReceived.Text =
            string.Format("{0} ({1})",
                downloader.TotalBytesReceived.ToHumanReadableSize(),
                string.Format("{0:0.00}%", downloader.Progress));
        segmentedProgressBar1.ContentLength = downloader.Info.ContentSize;
        segmentedProgressBar1.Bars = downloader.Ranges.ToList().Select(x => new Bar(x.TotalBytesReceived, x.Start, x.Status)).ToArray();
        lblResumeability.Text = downloader.Info.AcceptRanges ? "Yes" : "No";
        listView1.BeginUpdate();
        writeThreads();
        listView1.EndUpdate();
    }));
}

private void writeThreads()
{
    var ranges = downloader.Ranges.ToList();
    ranges = ranges.Where(x => !x.IsIdle).ToList();
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.Count; i++)
    {
        listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = (ranges[i].TotalBytesReceived.ToHumanReadableSize());
        listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text = (ranges[i].Status.ToString());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use BeginInvoke instead Invoke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DownloadProgressChanged` being fired on every chunk received e.g. for each 4kb received. You probably may update UI not for each call but only if percentage was changed.

```csharp
private int storedPercentage = -1;

private void downloader_ProgressChanged(object sender, EventArguments.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ProgressPercentage != storedPercentage)
    {
        storedPercentage = e.ProgressPercentage;
        this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            // existing code...
        }));
    }
}
```

**Disclamer:** exactly this way to fix is applicable only for single active download process. But the idea would be the same for concurrent downloads.

Comment: Ok this seems working. But i think there should be a solution for updating for every chunk

Comment: @AliTor you may tune it for performance. E.g not update the list/progress bar if not necessary. Learn something about `BindingList` collection to use it as `DataSource` for controls, etc. `HttpClient` instead of old `HttpWebRequest`/`WebClient` is way to go too. But main thing is find a balance between too often UI updates and too lazy.

Comment: @AliTor another idea is write the data to some structure and update UI from Timer, reading the data. I guess tha you don't need 1000 FPS to update the UI, make it not so often e.g. 10 times/sec.

Comment: @AliTor updated the answer, look where I changed `new Action` to `(Action)` it probably may save the memory and make less work for Garbage Collector. Thus it would be faster.